# Sort array alphanumerically

Tags: javascript

I have array like below , I want to sort it alphanumerically by ascending or descending in faster way.

```
[
  "NFO:BANKNIFTY1931428900CE",
  "NFO:BANKNIFTY1931429000CE",
  "NFO:BANKNIFTY1931429500CE",
  "NFO:BANKNIFTY1931429400CE",
  "NFO:BANKNIFTY1931429300CE",
  "NFO:BANKNIFTY1931429200CE"
]
```

I want to sort it like below , descending or ascending

```
[
  "NFO:BANKNIFTY1931429500CE",
  "NFO:BANKNIFTY1931429400CE",
  "NFO:BANKNIFTY1931429300CE",
  "NFO:BANKNIFTY1931429200CE",
  "NFO:BANKNIFTY1931429000CE",
  "NFO:BANKNIFTY1931428900CE",
]
```

I tried something like below  , but it does not sort properly and its slow too.

```
function sort() {
    var arr = disorderedArray;
    arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        a = a.split(" ");
        b = b.split(" ");
        var an = parseInt(a[0], 10);
        var bn = parseInt(b[0], 10);
        return an < bn ? 1 : (an > bn ? -1 : (a[1] < b[1] ? -1 : (a[1] > b[1] ? 1 : 0)));
    });
    console.log(arr.reverse());
}
```

Note: Sometimes it can involve mix of lowercase letters.

Answer (score 5):

Simply use `.sort()`.

```js
var items = [
  "NFO:BANKNIFTY1931428900CE",
  "NFO:BANKNIFTY1931429000CE",
  "NFO:BANKNIFTY1931429500CE",
  "NFO:BANKNIFTY1931429400CE",
  "NFO:BANKNIFTY1931429300CE",
  "NFO:BANKNIFTY1931429200CE"
]
var sorted = items.sort()
console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: This doesn't take in to consideration the numbers on similarly named strings. i.e.
...428900...
...429000...Higher Number (good)
...429500...Higher Number (good)
...429400...LOWER Number (not good)